# find the limit when $x$ approaches to $1$

Tags: limits

We have to find the limit of the following'
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{100}x^k\right)-100}{x-1}.$$

I thought to use sandwich theorm

But in I am not getting how to start .

Comment: Hint: calculate the sum, first: $\sum_{k=1}^{100}x^k = x \sum_{k=0}^{99}x^k = \cdots$

Comment: @dxiv after that

Comment: After that... well, why don't you actually *try* it first, then if you get stuck ask a specific question about *that*.

Comment: @dxiv: even I don't understand why you factored out an $x$. presumably your point is to get the OP to see a geometric series, but factoring out the $x$ isn't important.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Factoring out $x$ just makes the rest $1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{99}$ look more familiar.

Comment: @dxiv: I suppose I don't understand what makes you think this is more "familiar," but ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that the limit is the derivative $f'(1)$ with $f(x) = x+x^2+\cdots + x^{100}$

Comment: Can you explain it more

Comment: So the limit is 100? Nice answer, I was actually thinking of that but couldn't think of the function. Is there a way to do this without using the definition of the derivative

Comment: @wesssg can you explain to me , I didn't get it

Comment: @koolman what he did was used the definition of the derivative a point. Do you have that definition?

Comment: @wesssg no ,I don't

Comment: @wesssg L'Hopital, but using the definition directly is a lot neater.

Comment: @koolman I posted a picture of the definition for you

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\sum_{K=1}^{100}x^K=\frac{x-x^{101}}{1-x}$$

Then, apply L'Hospital's Rule twice.

Comment: After that @Dr.MV

Comment: Maybe think about it for more than 3 minutes, @koolman.

Comment: @Dr. MV:  You only need to apply it once.

Comment: @DeepSea Actually, twice since $$\frac{\sum_{K=1}^{100}x^K-100}{x-1}=-\frac{(x-x^{101}) -100(1-x)}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: @Dr.MV: You mean you take derivative of numerator and denominator, and not the derivative of the function.

Comment: @DeepSea There are many ways forward.  The proposed way herein is to use two successive applications of LHR.  This circumvents the need to sum the arithmetic series.

Answer (score 4):

We have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{100} x^k - 100}{x-1} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^{100} -100}{x-1} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(x-1) + (x^2 -1) + (x^3 -1) + ... + (x^{100} -1)}{x-1} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} 1 + (x+1) + (x^2 + x +1) + ... + (x^{99} +x^{98} + ...x +1) =  1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 100 = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{100}k = 5050. $

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Note that you can use this definition. This is the definition and then you can notice the function.

Comment: So in your case, $f(x) = x+x^2+\cdots + x^{100}$, $a=1$

Answer (score 2):

Hint (assuming the OP does indeed *not* know about derivatives or, by implication, l'Hopital's rule):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{100} x^k - 100 = \sum_{k=1}^{100} (x^k - 1)
$$